# Time complexity of recursive algorithm for denomination task

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I calculate all possible variants of input number k for 1, 2 or 5 numbers. It's easy algorithm for understanding:

```
//1,2,5
func foo(k: Int, result: [Int] = []) {
    if k == 0 {
        print(result)
        return
    }

    var one = result
    one.append(1)
    foo(k: k-1, result: one)

    if k >= 2 {
        var two = result
        two.append(2)
        foo(k: k-2, result: two)
    }

    if k >= 5 {
        var five = result
        five.append(5)
        foo(k: k-5, result: five)
    }
}
```

So, it works. My question is what is complexity (big O) of this algorithm?
I assume it's 3^k, because of 3 recursive calls inside.
Please prove or explain your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis of O(3^n) is correct, but it's not a tight bound because although the branching factor is (mostly) 3, the height of the right branches (n-5) is smaller than the middle (n-2) and left (n-1) branch.

The recurrence relation describing your code is: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-5) + 1`

Subtracting `T(n+1)` from `T(n)` (a standard trick to get rid of the constant) we get:

```
T(n+1) - T(n) = T(n) + T(n-1) + T(n-4) + 1 - T(n-1) - T(n-2) - T(n-5) - 1
T(n+1) = 2T(n) - T(n-2) + T(n-4) - T(n-5)
```

[This is a homogoneous linear recurrence relation, so has solutions of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation):

```
sum(A_i * a_i^n for i=0..5)
```

where A_i are (complex) constants, and a_i are roots of the equation x^6 = 2x^5 - x^3 + x - 1.

So the order of growth of T(n) will be O(a^n) where a is the largest magnitude root of the equation. [That happens to be real, and is approximately 1.7049](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6%20%3D%202x%5E5%20-%20x%5E3%20%2B%20x%20-%201).

So your code runs in O(1.705^n) time. Which is quite a lot better than O(3^n), although still of course exponential.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, and there are two keys to the analysis. Since you define the function with `k` as its argument, then let's write down the complexity in terms of `k`:

For `k >= 5`, foo solving the problem of size `k`is reduced to calling itself 3 times to solve smaller problems, each of size `k - c`, where `c` is a constant (in your case at most 5). Thus, you can write down the time complexity of foo as:

```
3 * f(k-1) >= f(k) >= 3 * f(k-5)
```

and the solution is clearly `f(k) = O(3^k)`, which you can proof for example by measuring the number of leaves in the recursion tree.